# How to post source code in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I noticed that when I post source code in a Blogger post, the code wraps to the next line if it's too long. I use the pre tag to post the code and I used different styles (overflow: auto; white-space: pre), still the code wraps in all browsers except in FireFox.

Is there a way to post source code without having the code wraps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the **word-wrap** property to **normal**.

Answer (score 9):

Checkout [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) if you already haven't. You can easily [integrate it with blogger](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/integration.html).

Comment: +1: Finally, a syntax highlighter that doesn't copy over the line numbers! Many thanks, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Use Code Prettify.

[I' have written some notes on how to.](http://pkario.blogspot.com/2010/04/blogger-code-prettifier.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using PreCode and SyntaxHighlighter for a while and it seems to work best for me. My blog readers also enjoy copy/pasting functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/), you can create "pretty" code which you can embed within a Blogger post. If you modify this code anytime, it will automatically show up in the blog post as well.

Answer (score -1):

Click on New Post
Then Compose Mode write your code there.
[image]

just write/paste code there.

Comment: How does it answer the question?