# How to highlight code in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, syntax-highlighting

I am using Google Blogger and would like to highlight the code. I tried a couple of ways, but not satisfied with the results.

Can anyone share how they have done it?

Comment: It would be great if you could list down what you've already tried.

Comment: I tried it a couple of weeks back and didn't like the once I tried and don't remember the names also.

Comment: Already Answered on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6456/how-to-post-source-code-in-blogger/67066#67066

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alex Gorbatchev's [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) is one of the most commonly used by software-related blogs for code highlighting. It [lists several blogs](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/integration.html) that provide steps how to integrate it with the Blogger service.

Answer (score 6):

Try [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). This is exactly what is used on StackExchange sites.

There is also good tool [here](http://codeformatter.blogspot.com/), that would generate a HTML block for you with some fancy formatting.

Comment: Google Prettify Link does not work anymore. Moved to GitHub https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Answer (score 0):

SyntaxHighlighter is not supported anymore.

Look at [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).

Here is a [Quick Start Demo](http://southstreamserbia-dotnet-pipe.blogspot.de/2015/03/highlightjs-v84-code-formatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. I like to embed code published in [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), alternatively [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/)
2. I like also [hilite.me](http://hilite.me/): converts your code snippets into pretty-printed HTML format, easily embeddable into blog posts, emails and websites.

Syntax Highlighter and Google Prettify does not support MATLAB Syntax highlighting,