# Blogger code highlighting in dynamic views

Tags: blogger

How to add syntax formatting to Blogger **in dynamic views**? I found [some](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/22186/16973) [links](http://heisencoder.net/2009/01/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-blogger.html) on topic, but unfortunately, all are proper for old style, not for dynamic views.

I liked [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/), so it is my first choice. Also [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is acceptable. Any way to highlight code in dynamic views with one of them?

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37830/29140

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the syntax highlighter: [kevin-junghans.blogspot](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/adding-syntaxhighlighter-to-blogger.html)

You just need to add this at the end of each post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
</script>
```