# How to highlight code AutoIt in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, syntax-highlighting

I am using Google Blogger and would like to highlight the code. I tried a couple of ways, but not satisfied with the results.

AutoIt Code it is not supported on JavaScript.

Can anyone share how they have done it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to highlight code in Blogger?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-to-highlight-code-in-blogger)

Comment: it does not support AutoIt, sir.